# Editing AndroidManifest.xml file of Acode 1.3.155 in Android 12

Tags: apk

*I am trying to edit Acode 1.3.155 in Android 12*

I tried renaming to .zip and extract it, it gave no error. 
But when i zipped it back and renamed it to .apk without changing anything in extracted folder, the package installer was throwing error.
I used Apk editor pro+ v2.3.2 ,
But again the package installer was throwing error on building back even though nothing was changed in any of the files.
So, I want to add permission given below because Acode 1.3.155 was giving Security error on opening any file (in Android 12)
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are simply ignored on Android 11+ as it requires to update the app to use Scoped Storage API. This is the reason you are getting permission denied errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you unzip an APK file and then re-compress it to a ZIP file you have removed the APK signature v2/v3 and thus the package installer will refuse to install it. Use `apksigner` from Android SDK to resign it.

`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are simply ignored on Android 11+ as it requires to update the app to use Scoped Storage API. This is the reason you are getting permission denied errors.

The only way to grant access for an app (that is just installed locally and not published via PlayStore) is to add `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission entry in it's `AndroidManifest.xml` and after installing the app you have to manually open the Android settings, select the app you have just installed and enable the slider `Allow access to manage all files`.

To modify an existing APK file you should use `apktool` on a PC. For modifying `AndroidManifest.xml` you don't need to decompile the sources so you can use the `--no-src` (`-s`) option:

```
java -jar apktool.jar d --no-src appxyz.apk
```

Now modify `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
java -jar apktool.jar b appxyz
```

Then align the built APK file using `zipalign -p 4 ...` and finally re-sign it.